# Vertical Slices: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple error

Tags: python

I have a two dimensional matrix in which I want to slice off vertical columns so that I can graph them. To do this, I want to use slice notation and a for loop so that I can produce the columns I need. In the code below I tried printing out each column to see if the slice notation would work.

```
Y_AXIS = [[1,2,3,4,5],
          [2,3,4,5,6],
          [3,4,5,6,7],
          [4,5,6,7,8]]

for i in range(5):
    print("Slice: ", Y_AXIS[:,i])
```

I want the code to print [1,2,3,4], then [2,3,4,5], and so on. Whenever it was run, however, the compiler threw an error saying "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple".

Comment: For a small amount of columns `list(zip(*Y_AXIS))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

y_axis = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], 
                   [2,3,4,5,6], 
                   [3,4,5,6,7], 
                   [4,5,6,7,8]])

for i in range(5):
    print(y_axis[:, i].tolist()) 

# output:
# Slice:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
# Slice:  [2, 3, 4, 5]
# Slice:  [3, 4, 5, 6]
# Slice:  [4, 5, 6, 7]
# Slice:  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

or you can use zip as  @Paul Rooney suggested:

```
Y_AXIS = [[1,2,3,4,5],
          [2,3,4,5,6],
          [3,4,5,6,7],
          [4,5,6,7,8]]

for i in zip(Y_AXIS):
    print("Slice: ", i)

# output:
# Slice:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
# Slice:  [2, 3, 4, 5]
# Slice:  [3, 4, 5, 6]
# Slice:  [4, 5, 6, 7]
# Slice:  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot slice the list like that if its not a numpy array, instead, if its a normal python list you should do this

```
Y_AXIS = [[1,2,3,4,5],
          [2,3,4,5,6],
          [3,4,5,6,7],
          [4,5,6,7,8]]


print("Slice: ", [[row[i] for row in Y_AXIS] for i in range(len(Y_AXIS[0]))])

# outputs
Slice:  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Another clever way is to `transpose` your numpy array.

```
Y_AXIS = np.array(Y_AXIS)
print(Y_AXIS.T)

[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 5]
 [3 4 5 6]
 [4 5 6 7]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```